# Saving Favorites to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have an app that displays posts from a website. I'm trying to add the ability for the user to save their favorite posts using NSUserDefaults. I need to save the title and url for each post the user wants to save as a favorite so I can display the title in a table view and then allow the user to select a favorite which then opens a web view with the corresponding url. I'm thinking I'll save the post title and url in a dictionary and then populate the table view from an array of the dictionaries. My problem is how can I save the dictionaries to begin with in NSUserDefaults without overriding a previous favorite that has been saved to user defaults? For example, the user saves a post to favorites dictionary which is then saved to user defaults. They then save another post to a dictionary, but that dictionary replaces the dictionary already in user defaults.

Here is what I tried. The favorites table view is only showing the last one saved.

```
- (void)addFavorite {
    NSMutableArray *favoritesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDictionary *favoriteDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.postTitle, @"title", self.postUrlString, @"url", nil];

    [favoritesArray addObject:favoriteDictionary];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoritesArray forKey:@"favorites"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Create custom accessor methods, likely on a singleton controller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it something like this

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *favoritesLoaded = [defaults objectForKey:@"favorites"];

    NSDictionary *fav = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         object.title, @"title",
                         object.url, @"url",
                         nil];

    NSMutableArray *favorites = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (favoritesLoaded) {
        favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:favoritesLoaded];
    } else {
        favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [favorites addObject:fav];

    [defaults setObject:favorites forKey:@"favorites"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this ( this is Swift 1.2)

```
func getPosts() -> [[String:String]]? {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("posts") as? [[String:String]]
}

func savePost(dictionary : [String:String]) {
    var newPosts : [[String:String]]
    if let existingPosts = getPosts() {
        newPosts = existingPosts;
        newPosts.append(dictionary);
    } else {
        newPosts = [dictionary]
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newPosts, forKey: "posts");
}
```